# The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' no longer has a Release file

Tags: apt, updates, 19.04

i have ubuntu 19.04
when i try `sudo apt-get update`

i get this

```
Ign:1 http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease                                                                                                                                           
Ign:4 http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                          
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release                                                                                                                                             
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Hit:6 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                       
Ign:7 http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                        
Err:8 http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release                                                                                                                                                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Hit:9 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable InRelease                                                                                                                                       
Err:10 http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release                                                                                                                                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Hit:11 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                          
Hit:12 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x disco InRelease         
Err:13 http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Hit:14 https://repos.influxdata.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

how can i fix this problem please help. 
thank you.

Comment: 19.04 is not supported anymore, you have to update to a supported release. See here: [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 reached end of life on Thursday, Jan 23rd. You should have updated to 19.10 long ago.

Comment: how should the update be done?